# Split my output into multiple files

Tags: perl, date, split

I have the following list in a CSV file, and my goal is to split this list into directories named `YYYY-Month` based on the date in each row.

```
NAME99;2018/06/13;12:27:30
NAME01;2018/06/13;13:03:59
NAME00;2018/06/15;11:33:01
NAME98;2018/06/15;12:22:00
NAME34;2018/06/15;16:58:45
NAME17;2018/06/18;15:51:10
NAME72;2018/06/19;10:06:37
NAME70;2018/06/19;12:44:03
NAME77;2018/06/19;16:36:55
NAME25;2018/06/11;16:32:57
NAME24;2018/06/11;16:32:57
NAME23;2018/06/11;16:37:15
NAME01;2018/06/11;16:37:15
NAME02;2018/06/11;16:37:15
NAME01;2018/06/11;16:37:18
NAME02;2018/06/05;09:51:17
NAME00;2018/06/13;15:04:29
NAME07;2018/06/19;10:02:26
NAME08;2018/06/26;16:03:57
NAME09;2018/06/26;16:03:57
NAME02;2018/06/27;16:58:12
NAME03;2018/07/03;07:47:21
NAME21;2018/07/03;10:53:00
NAMEXX;2018/07/05;03:13:01
NAME21;2018/07/05;15:39:00
NAME01;2018/07/05;16:00:14
NAME00;2018/07/08;11:50:10
NAME07;2018/07/09;14:46:00
```

What is the smartest method to achieve this result without having to create a list of static routes, in which to carry out the append?

Currently my program writes this list to a directory called `YYYY-Month` only on the basis of `localtime` but does not do anything on each line.

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature qw(say);

use File::Path qw<mkpath>;
use File::Spec;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX qw<strftime>;

my $OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.csv';
my $OUTFILE     = 'splitted_output.csv';

# Output to file
open( GL_INPUT, $OUTPUT_FILE ) or die $!;
$/ = "\n\n";    # input record separator

while ( <GL_INPUT> ) {

    chomp;
    my @lines = split /\n/;

    my $i = 0;

    foreach my $lines ( @lines ) {

        # Encapsulate Date/Time
        my ( $name, $y, $m, $d, $time ) =
                $lines[$i] =~ /\A(\w+);(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+);(\d+:\d+:\d+)/;    

        # Generate Directory YYYY-Month - #2009-January
        my $dir = File::Spec->catfile( $BASE_LOG_DIRECTORY, "$y-$m" ) ;
        unless ( -e $dir ) {
            mkpath $dir;
        }

        my $log_file_path = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $OUTFILE );
        open( OUTPUT, '>>', $log_file_path ) or die $!;

        # Here I append value into files
        print OUTPUT join ';', "$y/$m/$d", $time, "$name\n";    
        
        $i++;
    }
}

close( GL_INPUT );
close( OUTPUT );
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do please? I understood that you want to create smaller files with a sub-set based on year and month. So the first line of your input file should go into a file in the directory `2018-06/` and the last line should go into a different file in the directory `2018-07/`. Is that correct?

Comment: And how many output files do you expect? (the solution gets more complicated if you need many - as in several thousand - files)

Comment: @simbabque yes, it's correct :)

Comment: You do realize your code does something completely different?

Comment: @Henrik My csv contain last access on a server. I think to found only last two months on my csv log file.

Comment: @simbaque My code actualy write into 2018-July directory, because it works with locatime :(

Comment: You don't need to care about today's date. You care about some value in each line of data, which happens to represent a date.

Comment: @simbabque You're absolutely right, I was thinking badly.
I've updated the code right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to care about the actual date, or to use date functions at all here. You want to split up your data based on a partial value of one of the columns in the data. That just happens to be the date.

> ```
> NAME08;2018/06/26;16:03:57   # This goes to 2018-06/
> NAME09;2018/06/26;16:03:57   #
> NAME02;2018/06/27;16:58:12   #
> NAME03;2018/07/03;07:47:21      # This goes to 2018-07/
> NAME21;2018/07/03;10:53:00      #
> NAMEXX;2018/07/05;03:13:01      #
> NAME21;2018/07/05;15:39:00      #
> ```

The easiest way to do this is to iterate your input data, then stick it into a hash with keys for each year-month combination. But you're talking about log files, and they might be large, so that's inefficient.

We should work with different file handles instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %months = ( 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July' );

my %handles;
while (my $row = <DATA>) {

    # no chomp, we don't actually care about reading the whole row
    my (undef, $dir) = split /;/, $row; # discard name and everything after date

    # create the YYYY-MM key
    $dir =~ s[^(....)/(..)][$1-$months{$2}];

    # open a new handle for this year/month if we don't have it yet
    unless (exists $handles{$dir}) {
        # create the directory (skipped here) ...
        open my $fh, '>', "$dir/filename.csv" or die $!;
        $handles{$dir} = $fh;
    }

    # write out the line to the correct directory
    print { $handles{$dir} } $row;
}

__DATA__
NAME08;2018/06/26;16:03:57
NAME09;2018/06/26;16:03:57
NAME02;2018/06/27;16:58:12
NAME03;2018/07/03;07:47:21
NAME21;2018/07/03;10:53:00
NAMEXX;2018/07/05;03:13:01
NAME21;2018/07/05;15:39:00
```

I've skipped the part about creating the directory as you already know how to do this.

This code will also work if your rows of data are not sequential. It's not the most efficient as the number of handles will grow the more data you have, but as long you don't have 100s of them at the same time that does not really matter.

Things of note:

- You don't need `chomp` because you don't care about working with the last field.
- You don't need to assign all of the values after `split` because you don't care about them.
- You can discard values by assigning them to `undef`.
- Always use three-argument `open` and *lexical* file handles.
- the `{}` in `print { ... } $row`are needed to tell Perl that this is the handle we are printing too. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html.

Comment: Oh. You wanted the month name, not the `MM` numbers. In that case, my regex does not make much sense. But you could use a lookup hash.

Comment: After my last edit, my code works ♥. What do you think about it ? Now i study your code, for undestand your solution...

Comment: @Perler I am happy you got it to work on your own! That's great! Some of the points in my answer already address code review. Your solution is very complex. You re-open file handles all the time, and don't explicitly close them. You use extra modules that are not really needed. I would reject it as too complicated and inefficient in a $work code review I'm afraid. Feel free to post it to [codereview.se] for an in-depths review. :)